# Error processing query with Olingo, JPA and either EclipseLink or Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, olingo

I am working on a proof of concept to create a service to access an existing Oracle database with an OData service. The idea is to use a Olingo and JPA, explicitly JPA annotations in the model. We are currently agnostic about which provider to use. We have experimented with both EclipseLink and Hibernate so far and have hit a similar problem.

The database schema uses NUMBER(28,0) for the key for all of the tables. As I understand it, the appropriate JPA declaration for that in the model is:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id", scale = 28, precision = 0)
private BigDecimal id;
```

An OData query for this would look like:

```
http://localhost:8081/myservice.svc/PO(10000000000000000000000080M)
```

Notice that we actually have data with keys in this range. For tables where the keys are lower numbers we everything works fine.

I've debugged into the handling of this and found that Olingo produces an JPQL representation, which from my reading of the specs is correct.

```
SELECT E1 FROM PO E1 WHERE E1.id = 10000000000000000000000080
```

At this point it goes into provider specific code to try translate that into a proper SQL query. Both Hibernate and EclipseLink fail to recognize that literal. It seems as though the translation into their internal formats during the conversion should result in that number having a qualifier to indicate that it is a large integer.

The failures of the 2 systems are actually different. EclipseLink creates a select that has "where id is null". Hibernate throws an exception.

The questions that I have are:

1. Is there some alternative way for me to define my model so that this falls into the right processing and succeeds?
2. Are these bugs that I should be reporting to the respective providers?
3. If these are bugs, can anyone recommend an alternative provider that doesn't fail on this?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have control over the JPQL ? by that i mean, if you could define it as "SELECT E1 FROM PO E1 WHERE E1.id = ?" and specify the value as a parameter then they *may* work. All bugs should be reported.

Comment: I don't believe that I do have control over the generation of JPQL. Even if I did, my best understand of the JPQL is that it is correct. There is no syntax for differentiating big integer literals.

As to reporting bugs. I agree that they should be reported. However, I want to be certain that they are bugs before I report them.

Comment: My point is not as to whether it is correct, it obviously is. My point is to provide a workaround. If you don't have access to JPQL then it's not important.

Comment: Which exception is thrown by Hibernate?

Comment: The initial exception is a NumberFormatException caused by trying to parse that number (10000000000000000000000080) using Long.parseLong in LiteralProcessor.determineIntegerRepresentation. This appears to occur because the literal is not being categorized as a big integer.

That is caught in determineIntegerRepresentation and wrapped in a HibernateException with the message "Could not parse literal [10000000000000000000000080] as integer".
That is caught in AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert and wrapped in a PersistenceException.

Comment: I just tried that with the provider I use (DataNucleus JPA) and it worked fine, recognising the parameter as BigInteger and putting that in the resultant SQL.